When should each of 里, 里边, 里面, and 里头 be used?
"inside" in Chinese
What is the difference between
里
里边
里面
里头
When should each one of them be used?
For example, "I'm inside the house" - should it be
我在家里

里/里边/里面/里头 are interchangeable in most cases, including 我在家里. Some special cases:

If the object before 里/里边/里面/里头 is omitted, i.e., you’re mainly emphasizing inside as opposed to outside, don’t use 里. For example, 外面很危险，我想留在里面.
里头 is a little colloquial compared to 里/里边/里面.

I usually use 里 if possible and I prefer to use 里边/里面/里头 to emphasize "inside".

"When should each one of them be used?"
Here's a general usage example:-
他从车里看到房子里面有很多昂贵的家具在里头
